# cell text not shown properly after setting background color in jtable

Tags: swing, jtable

After I set background color of a cell, when I select the cell the text changes its color to white I think( not clearly visible) It used to be black.
I am using

```
cell.setBackground( Color.yellow )
```

in my Custom cell renderer
Should I add anything else to make the text properly visible?

Answer (score 0):

Change the foreground color:

```
cell.setForeground( Color.BLACK );
```

Comment: If I use this, after selecting a line in the tree table ( the line selection appears as a blue line say) this particular cell is not highlighted with blue, other cells are highlighted.